# Eslint - `Parsing error: unexpected token =` error for assigned fat arrow / property initializer

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, class-fields

I'm using an arrow function and it's complaining about a parsing error:

`Parsing Error: Unexpected token =`

However my code is valid (please tell me if i'm mistaken). Additionally, i've set the .eslintrc settings to use es6 parsing:

**.eslintrc**

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
    }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
class foo() {
     // Doesn't like the line below
     // even though it is valid:
     namedFunction = () => {

     }

}
```

There a way to resolve this error? This makes a huge different in terms of what the value of `this` from a particular function.

Comment: I believe that's because it wants you use to `namedFunction() { ... }` inside a class

Comment: But it is inside the class from the code i've written above right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're using class field (a.k.a. property initializer) syntax, which is not part of ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), nor ES2016 or 2017, and so unsupported by ESLint. It's currently a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). If you want to use it with ESLint, you'll need to use [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint). That page describes how to use it, but the gist is:

> #### Installation
>
> ```sh
> $ npm install eslint babel-eslint --save-dev
> # or
> $ yarn add eslint babel-eslint -D
> ```
>
> **Note:** babel-eslint requires `babel/core@>=7.2.0` and a valid Babel configuration file to run. If you do not have this already set up, please see the [Babel Usage Guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage).
>
> #### Setup
>
> To use babel-eslint, `"babel-eslint"` must be specified as the `parser` in your ESLint configuration file (see [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser) for more detailed information).
>
> **.eslintrc.js**
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   parser: "babel-eslint",
> };
> ```
>
> With the parser set, your configuration can be configured as described in the [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) documentation.

Answer (score 23):

In 2021 it seems that `babel-eslint` has been deprecated in favour of `@babel/eslint-parser`, according to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint):

> NOTE: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser and has moved into the Babel monorepo.

So to update the instructions from the other answers, you need to:

```sh
npm i eslint @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
```

Then make sure you configure the `parser` key in `.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  ...
}
```

As an aside, as the OP doesn't mention the runtime, I'm running in Node 12 so I don't need babel to transpile my code but ESlint *does* need babel to lint the code (sounds weird but that's my understanding). So I also needed a basic babel config, `babel.config.json`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "12"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"` not worked for me, I had to replace to `"parser": "babel-eslint"`

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem. The accepted answer is correct, as far as it goes, and very helpful. But I use a json version of the eslint config, not a javascript one, so once babel-eslint was installed using:

```sh
npm i eslint babel-eslint --save-dev
```

I had to change my json config. It looks like this now:

**`.eslintrc.json`**

```json
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "es6": true,
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": 0
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that native support for [Public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) without the need for a babel parser is now finally supported in Eslint since eslint8 with setting ecmaVersion: 13.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `ecmaVersion` in the `.eslintrc.js` file to solve the problem.

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    },
}
```